# Ansible (2.11 +) error with winrm when path invalid in environment variable (win_stat task)

Tags: ansible, winrm

we have an Ansible script to deploy software on Windows. One of the task if to check the existence of a folder with win_stat command.

However, om some servers, the task throws an error when a path that doesn't exist is defined in the 'LIB' environment variable on the windows server (the path has nothing to do with what we check)

I'm able to reproduce with a dead simple script:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Check addon folder
      win_stat:
        path: 'C:\temp\'
```

and the error is (with verbose):

```
The full traceback is:
(0) : Warning as Error: Invalid search path 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified. '

(1) : using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

At line:408 char:5
+     Add-Type -TypeDefinition $link_util
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

ScriptStackTrace:
at Load-LinkUtils, <No file>: line 408
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 76
fatal: [IADCMP019]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: (0) : Warning as Error: Invalid search path 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' specified in 'LIB environment variable' -- 'The system cannot find the path specified. '\n\n(1) : using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;\n"
}
```

Problems happens with 2.11.6 and 2.11.4 of Ansible core, but not with 2.10 (at least 2.10.9)

I'm wondering if it's a new check in 2.11 or if it's something I should open a bug report about.

EDIT1: changed 'c:' to 'c:\temp' as the win_stat command is long on the former, much faster on the later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't looking in the right repository for this. The bug is already opened, on ansible.windows collection : https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.windows/issues/297

Comment: feels weird to accept your own answer, especially if it points to a bug report, but it could help others.

Comment: Fix was merged into Ansible collection, so we should have a fix in current versions

Comment: The workaround with setting the LIB variable to nothing also fixed the win_acl module for me in ansible 2.10.